# mysql: return column for each subquery result

Tags: mysql

I have 3 tables: `customers`, `orders`, and `order-items`. The question asks to write a SELECT statement that will return a table with

- a customer's email address
- the number of orders for that customer
- and the total cost for each order

The first two points are fairly straight-forward:

```
SELECT email_address,
       (SELECT SUM(order_id) 
        FROM orders 
        WHERE orders.customer_id = cust.customer_id) as "order_count"
FROM customers as cust
```

And I know I can get the `order_total` for each order like this:

```
SELECT order_id, 
    (SELECT SUM((item_price - discount_amount) * quantity)
     FROM order_items 
     WHERE order_items.order_id = ord.order_id) as "order_total"
FROM orders AS ord
```

But, if I try to combine them and do something like:

```
SELECT email_address,
       (SELECT SUM(order_id)
        FROM orders AS ord
        WHERE ord.customer_id = cust.customer_id) as "order_count",
       (SELECT(SELECT SUM((item_price - discount_amount) * quantity)
         FROM order_items 
         WHERE order_items.order_id = ord.order_id)
         FROM orders AS ord
         WHERE ord.customer_id = cust.customer_id) as "order_total"
FROM customers as cust;
```

I get:

> Subquery returns more than 1 row

I understand why I'm getting that error. Because yes, the subquery does return multiple rows. What I want is for each of those rows' value to be placed in another column (at least that's what I interpret the question to ask for). For example:

```
email_address    |  order_count  |  order1_total  |  order2_total  |  etc...
============================================================================
john_doe@foo.com |      2        |     $100       |       $200     |   NULL
```

**The DB's tables look like:**

customers(customer_id, email_address)
orders(order_id, customer_id)
order_items(item_id, order_id, item_price, discount_amount, quantity)

**The question as it's phrased in the assignment:**
(which I think is really poorly worded, but what do I know?) :)

Write a SELECT statement that returns one row for each customer that has orders with these columns:

- The email_address from the Customers table
- A count of the number of orders
- The total amount for each order (Hint: First, subtract the discount amount from the price. Then, multiply by the quantity.)

Return only those rows where the customer has more than 1 order.
Sort the result set in descending sequence by the sum of the line item amounts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may avoid such corrlated subqueries by instead using aggregation with `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
    c.email_address,
    COUNT(DISTINCT o.order_id) AS num_orders,
    COALESCE(SUM(oi.quantity * (oi.item_price - oi.discount_amount)), 0) AS total_amount
FROM customers c
LEFT JOIN orders o
    ON c.customer_id = o.customer_id
INNER JOIN order_items oi
    ON o.order_id = oi.order_id
GROUP BY
    c.customer_id,
    c.email_address;
```